# Restrict application access to specific policies in AAD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way (either in the portal or otherwise) to restrict access to policies? For example, I can specify what sign-in policy I want to use in my application (say, only Google and Internal logins) but if a developer changes the policy value in the application to call a different policy that allows Facebook logins (which we don't want but the policy does exist in the portal), how can we enforce security on this situation? Is there a way we can restrict access to policies for only applications that are allowed to access them?

Comment: There is no way to bind a policy to an application today. If you explain your scenario, there may be an alternate mechanism to achieve it.